# Can't Delete an Encryption Key Created by Amazon SES

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-kms

I was messing around with AWS SES for the first time, and let the service create some default encryption keys for a new organization to encrypt emails.  However, when I deleted that organization, the keys stayed behind.  I am now unable to schedule them for deletion because I don't have the requisite permissions, even when signed as the root user.  Here is the current policy for these keys:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Id": "auto-ses-2",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Sid": "Allow SES to encrypt messages belonging to this account",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ses.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": [
        "kms:Encrypt",
        "kms:GenerateDataKey*"
      ],
      "Resource": "*",
      "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
          "kms:EncryptionContext:aws:ses:source-account": "915144628597"
        },
        "Null": {
          "kms:EncryptionContext:aws:ses:rule-name": "false",
          "kms:EncryptionContext:aws:ses:message-id": "false"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "Sid": "Allow SES to describe this key",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ses.us-east-1.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "kms:DescribeKey",
      "Resource": "*"
    },
    {
      "Sid": "Allow direct access to key metadata & decryption to the account",
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::915144628597:root"
      },
      "Action": [
        "kms:Describe*",
        "kms:Get*",
        "kms:List*",
        "kms:Decrypt",
        "kms:ReEncryptFrom"
      ],
      "Resource": "*"
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see, the root account has neither permission to schedule key deletion, nor even to put a new key policy.  So as far as I can tell, I have literally no way of removing these keys.  All documentation and previous posts that I could find on this matter assume that the user created the key themselves, which I did not.  So I thought I'd ask the community for suggestions before messing with filing a customer service ticket.  Your help is much appreciated!

Comment: Anyone?  Thoughts??

Comment: How did you create that key? Manually or using CloudFormation? Generally, KMS requires you to add a key administrator when creating that key, to reduce the risk of rendering a key unmanageable.